# Two way link task sheet - Excel/Access

Tags: excel, list, ms-access, synchronization, task

Currently at work I am trying to create a task sheet system. Basically for each job there will be a Master sheet with a variety of tasks for several different people, from this I'm looking to create a task sheet specific to each person. I would like to be able to add a task on the Master sheet and it appear on the respective person's page. As well as this, if the person makes a note on their personal sheet then it would appear on the Master.

However the complicated part is that there is constantly multiple job's with their own Master sheet and I want each of these to contribute to the persons overall task list.

Could anyone please suggest how I go about this? I have attempted using Google Sheets but I can't get the two way sync to work. So I was thinking of using a combination of Microsoft Access to store the data and Excel to present it.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well I'm a database app designer; so for a database - any data set which includes a field for a person ID - - is then easily queried by Person ID so that you have another 'view' or set of data just for that person...….. so in the database world this is very straight forward.... as to linking sheets in google docs or even the implementation in excel I have no idea.....

Comment: Yeah I'm beginning to think this is more of a database type scenario, could you recommend a good beginner database system that I might be able to tackle this with? The only reason for needing to use Google Sheets or Excel is making it simple for my co-workers

Comment: the only PC database left is Access, unless you are MAC then it is FileMaker.  If you are anti Microsoft then probably it is MySQL.  ….but beyond that I don't delve into shareware or hobby products.....and there could be other stuff out there...